# Display Zend Form Validation error in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

There is a Zend Registration Form. Having as input username, email, password and confirm password. Validator for email is following:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email_reg',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StripTags',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'StringTrim',
            ),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
            'name' => 'EmailAddress',
            'options' => array(
                'domain' => true,
                'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Email address format is invalid'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                'options' => array(
                    'table' => 'user',
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'adapter' =>  $sm->get ( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ),
                    'messages' => array(
                    NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'E-mail address already exists'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

There are 4 validators: Required Type, e-amil format and if there is someone with following e-mail in database.
Error messages will be:
- E-mail is required
- Email address format is invalid
- E-mail address already exists

**Problem** Trying to catch error messages and output using ajax. In RegisterController having following function:

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL,
            array( 'controller' => 'index'
            )
        );
    }

    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegisterForm');
    $form->setInputFilter(new RegisterFilter($this->getServiceLocator()));  
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $form->setData($post);
    $response   = $this->getResponse();
    $hello = 1;
    if (!$form->isValid()){
        // email is invalid; print the reasons
        $json= $form->getMessages();
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

And jQuery file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
         var urlform = "register/ajax";
    $("#btnRegister").click( function() {
        $("#Register").submit( function() {
           return false;    
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: urlform,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: $(".form-signin").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#rCheck").text(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#rCheck").text(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

In Console i got something like this https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/558x205q90/661/uC09Da.png and in div with id #rCheck getting [Object][Object].

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided the error messages are correctly returned. The error is that you are trying to write directly an `Object` into your `div`.

You should have seached how to read an object with JavaScript. Try with this code :

```
success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(function(datum) {
               Object.keys(datum).forEach(function (key) {
                $('<p>'+obj[key]+'</p>').appendTo('#rCheck');
                });
            });
            console.log(data);
        },
```

Or you may also do that within your `ajaxAction` :

```
$messages = array();
$errors = $form->getMessages();
foreach($errors as $key=>$row)
{
    if (!empty($row) && $key != 'submit') {
        foreach($row as $keyer => $rower)
        {
            $messages[$key][] = $rower;    
        }
    }
}
if (!empty($messages)){ 
$response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($messages));
}
return $response;
```

Here's is a good [post](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/) on how to use `Zend\Form` with Ajax validation.

Comment: Using in Ajax Give error. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @user3904245 please provide the errors you're getting.